# Why do javascript implementations parse numbers this way?

Tags: javascript

According to the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) the integer part of a decimal number should be either zero or start with a non-zero digit. A hexadecimal value should start with 0x.

Javascript, in the major browsers, extends EMCAScript to include octal numbers. These are determined by having a sequence of digits (from 0 to 7 inclusive) start with a zero.

Given these facts, my naive implementation of a javascript interpreter would probably parse integers a bit like this:

```
if first_char in [1-9] then
    parse_input_as_decimal()
else if first_char is 0 then
    if second_char is 'x' then
        parse_input_as_hexadecimal()
    else if second_char in [1-7] then
        parse_input_as_octal()
    else
        parse_input_as_zero()
```

However the web browsers seem to act slightly weird in that if a number beginning with zero contains the digits 8 or 9 then it reads it as a valid decimal. This can lead to oddities, especially when using a decimal point or exponent. Some examples:

```
011 // is octal
0011 // is octal
019 // is decimal
0091 // is decimal
011.0 // throws an error
019.0 // is decimal
011e5 // throws an error
019e5 // is decimal
```

My question is why do they behave like this? Is it just some quirk of history? Or is there a good reason? Is it written in some spec somewhere? Will this ever change?

I know this is a bit arcane and few people use octals in javascript these days, but I'm curious.

Comment: Related from SO - [Javascript, why treated as octal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071696/javascript-why-treated-as-octal) - though the reason ultimately is "that is the way many other C like syntax languages do it."

Comment: It was a silly overload to add to a higher level language meant to be accessible to a wide variety of skill-levels. I'm not embarrassed to admit that it ruined close to a day of my life.

Comment: Note: on the above I mistakenly thinking of the parseInt/parseFloat ocal overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Quirk:'strict mode' gets rid of this behavior, I think it was a non standard behavior that a couple browsers implemented but I'm not 100% (about it being non-standard, I am sure about it being removed from strict JavaScript)

Comment: The '0...' overload is also no longer present in modern browsers (well, Chrome and I believe FF at least) and set to not act that way in the more recent specs. It was a doozy of a bug for every JS dev splitting out dollars and cents from strings in the html. Definitely a "bad part" we could all agree on.

Comment: 0011 comes up as 9 in the console of chrome 27 (aka up to date version I am using right now)

Comment: With what method?

Comment: open up dev tools, go to console, type 0011, response is 9

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of the parseInt and parseFloat overloads where '08' gave you 0 or '010' gave you 8.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior